# Stock picking from fleet model - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo

I'm trying to create a `stock.picking` from `fleet.vehicle.log.services` model on Odoo v9 community.

So far I'm trying like this:

```
stock_picking = fields.Many2one("stock.picking", "Picking", required=True)
state = fields.Selection(string="Estados", store=True, readonly=True, related="stock_picking.state")
product_id = fields.Many2one(string="Producto", store=True, readonly=True, related="stock_picking.product_id")
location_id = fields.Many2one(string="Almacén Origen", store=True, readonly=True, related="stock_picking.location_id")
location_dest_id = fields.Many2one(string="Almacén Destino", store=True, readonly=True, related="stock_picking.location_dest_id")
```

The result of this, is that every time I create a `stock.picking` from this form model (fleet.vehicle.log.services), it populates the `product` and `location` fields with the ones from the picking I've just created.

So, what is the problem here? Well, I need to put the product and locations from this `form` not just bring the ones from the picking, the relationship should work in reverse.

I hope I've explained myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related field in Odoo is read only field (you dont need to put option readonly in field when using related field) and the value will be filled automatically from the related model field (in this case product and location values will have same value with related model fields). 
If you want to input the value yourself, just remove related field option for product and location.

```
product_id = fields.Many2one("stocking.picking", string="Producto", store=True,readonly=True)
location_id = fields.Many2one("stock.picking", string="Almacén Origen", store=True, readonly=True)
location_dest_id = fields.Many2one("stock.picking", string="Almacén Destino", readonly=True)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You very much, but this only brings 'stock.picking' not the products, I don't get it, every field brings a stock.picking, should I Many2one to product instead?

Comment: Indeed, part of the problem was the readonly and related, but this relationship only takes a stock.picking, so, I think I should bring product.template and location_id? How can I bring location_id from stock.picking if it's not related? Thank You!

Comment: Oh yes, if you want to select product, you should many2one to product model. There are many ways to get the location_id from stock_picking. You could use related for this field to get the same location_id, or you could use default_get to set the default location_id and let the user select a different one if they want

Comment: Thank You, gonna try if I have more issues I'll open a new question